# angularjs - Ionic/Angular1 Tlantic/cdv-socket-plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sockets

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConnected' of null

```
at PosCommunicator.isConnected (app.all.min.js:2926)
at app.all.min.js:3298
at Scope.$emit (libs.all.min.js:56256)
at Object.emit (libs.all.min.js:83720)
at Object.transition (libs.all.min.js:83550)
at libs.all.min.js:85379
at libs.all.min.js:83428
at Object.render (libs.all.min.js:83517)
at Object.init (libs.all.min.js:83427)
at Object.self.render (libs.all.min.js:85373)
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined

```
at app.all.min.js:40
at Array.<anonymous> (libs.all.min.js:81844)
at onPlatformReady (libs.all.min.js:28102)
at onWindowLoad (libs.all.min.js:28083)
```

I installed Tlantic/cdv-socket-plugin 
but socketplugin method cannot loaded ('isConnected' of null)
Anyone can help me to solve this problem.

https://github.com/Tlantic/cdv-socket-plugin

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: do you use PosCommunicator = window.tlantic.plugins.socket ? If so could you console.log(window.tlantic) before using that? if this is undefined then the plugin is not loaded